# Hierarchical JSON Data to Hierarchical Table

Tags: c#, sql, json.net

I have a class like this and to this type I need to deserialize a JSON string

```
public class nodes
{
    public int id{get;set;}
    public string name{get;set;}
    public List<nodes> children{get;set;}
}
```

and the JSON is like  this

```
{
  id: 15,
  name: 'user1',
  children: [
    {
      id: 22,
      name: 'user2',
      children: [
        {
          id: 34,
          name: 'user3',
          children: [
            {
              id: 43,
              name: 'user4',
              children: []
            },
            {
              id: 54,
              name: 'user5',
              children: []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 65,
          name: 'user6',
          children: []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 72,
      name: 'user7',
      children: []
    }
  ]
}
```

This is how I'm deserialising

```
node d=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<node>(myJSON); //myJSON is my above JSON string
```

But the requirement is I need to insert these data into an SQL table as separate rows. The table should is as follows

```
UniqueID    id    name    ParentID
------------------------------------
    1       15    User1     0
    2       22    User2     1
    3       34    User3     2
    4       43    User4     3
    5       54    User5     3
    6       65    User6     2
    7       72    User7     1
--------------------------------------
```

As you see the table there is a system generated ID column `UniqueID`. Also another column `ParentID` to keep the hierarchy..

I can ofcourse use some recursive functions to handle each children to their details and create a dynamic query to insert. But I dont think its a best solution. Please suggest a better way to do this

Comment: Recursive function sounds good here, why do you think it's not the best solution.

Comment: That is true, But I thought it will be great to have a straight away conversion to avoid that recursion if the JSON is huge

Comment: But the conversion will have to be recursive in some way regardless whether you go to objects first, then to database or if you just parse the Json string directly into the database. Your data structure is recursive itself.

Comment: OK, If you also feels thats the good option Im proceeding with it. Thanks mate..

Answer (score 2):

How about flattening your tree via Linq (it is still going to use recursion), I think it may make it clearer. You could then just loop throught the result. I'm thinking something like this:

First write an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> c,
    Func<T,IEnumerable<T>> f) 
{
    return c.SelectMany(n => f(n).Flatten(f)).Concat(c);
}
```

Then you can flatten and loop:

```
var nodesList = nodes.Flatten(node => node.children).ToList();

foreach(var n in nodeList)
{
    /add to db
}
```